# sqlite and hebrew variations

Tags: sqlite

SELECT * FROM table WHERE word = "רֵאשִׁית" 
would return results that contain given word, but same words ( בְּרֵאשִׁית 
 ,בראשית
 ,רֵאשִׁית) that are written using different hebrew variants are ignored.

Is there a way to ignore the difference between the variants in order to have them all in the result returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm used to compare strings is called a [collation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation).

To allow using custom collation rules, you have to use SQLite's C API to register your own collation function: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html

If you're on Android: the OS registers a collation named `UNICODE`, which implements the [Unicode Collation Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/), which may or may not do what you want.

Other SQLite installations may have been compiled with the [ICU extension](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/artifact/bf8461d8cdc6b8f514c080e4e10dc3b2bbdfefa9).